# Ghosting in [CALayer drawInContext]

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation, calayer, quartz-graphics

I'm drawing as scrollable graph using a custom extension of `CALayer` with a bunch of `CGContextAddCurveToPoint` calls in `[ MyCustomCALayer drawInContext]`.

I'm not actually drawing the whole length of the graph, rather, I'm redrawing the contents of the layer every time a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` updates to reflect the new horizontal offset. This way, I only draw the visible portion of the graph, and the layer's bounds only extend to the size of the screen.

`[ MyCustomCALayer setNeedsDisplay ]` gets called when graph data changes or the pan offset changes, which then causes `[ MyCustomCALayer drawInContext]` to be invoked.

However, I'm getting this weird ghosting whenever I redraw my layer during panning. A bit of searching around suggests it might be an [implicit animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006085-SW7) invoked by redrawing the layer's content, but I can't find a definitive answer.

Here's what the graph looks like at rest:
[image: At rest]

And here it is during panning, with the ghosting redraw:
[image: During panning]

Certainly, when I *do* draw the whole graph and adjust the layer's `position` property to pan it's not ghosting, but having a big long bitmap in memory seems like a Bad Thing.

Has anyone seen this kind of ghosting before? If it is (as I suspect) an implicit animation, how can I disable said animation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will probably be an implicit animation. Redraws (changes in contents) are animated like everything else in Core Animation.

There are a number of ways to prevent this, if you're subclassing CALayer to do the drawing the best is to override -[CALayer actionForKey:], returning nil for change in contents:

```
- (id<CAAction>)actionForKey:(NSString *)key 
{
    if ([key isEqualToString: @"contents"]) 
    {
        return nil;
    }

    return [super actionForKey: key];
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @joerick, good answer and did the trick nicely.

Comment: One thing to note: actionForKey: can also be used to enable implicit animation for custom properties of your CALayer subclass. Interesting stuff! Thanks for the answer, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Another technique of disabling implicit animations is:

```
    [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
```

If disabling implicit animations doesn't do it, then you could consider using a scroll view and drawing the whole thing in a large view that is then the content of that scroll view.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that that method requires you do your modifications within a CATransaction block